# upload a file (name by id)

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload

i want to upload a file by my php, my code is like this :

```
$hasil = mysql_query("select ID from userownfile order by ID DESC");
$dt = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
$old_id = substr($dt['ID'],2);

$newId = $old_id[0] + 1;

$base = $_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = $newId . ".jpg";
$buffer = base64_decode($base);
$path = "img/" . $filename . ".jpg";
$handle = fopen($path, 'wb');
$numbytes = fwrite($handle, $buffer);
fclose($handle);
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db_bloodglucose");
$sql = "insert into userownfile(ID, file) values('" . $newId . "','" . $path . "')";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
```

at first upload, i've succed to upload a file which name is 1.jpg, but when i want to upload the second time etc, it didn't show up on my database, it keep showing 1.jpg, i wonder why the number didn't increase.. anyone can help me? thanks before

i've been change my code like this :

```
<?php

$hasil = mysql_query("select ID from userownfile order by ID DESC");
$dt = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
$old_id = substr($dt['ID'],2);

$newId = mysql_insert_id() + 1;

$base = $_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = $newId . ".jpg";
$buffer=base64_decode($base);
$path = "img/".$filename.".jpg";
$handle = fopen($path, 'wb');
$numbytes = fwrite($handle, $buffer);
fclose($handle);
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db_bloodglucose");
$sql = "insert into userownfile(ID, file) values('" . $newId . "','" . 

$path . "')";
$r=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

but, it keep stuck to 1, the number isn't increasing, anyone can help me please?

Comment: Does anything actually get inserted into the database on the first try?

Comment: @Handy see my question above - does anything get inserted into the database?

Comment: @pekka, the first one get inserted on my database, 1.jpg, but when i try again the 2nd etc, it didn't work... i've set my id into "no auto increment"

Answer (score 0):

I guess mistake is here:

```
$dt = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)
$old_id = substr($dt['ID'],2);
$newId = $old_id[0]+1;
```

may be

```
$newId = $dt[0]+1;
```

or just

```
$newId = $old_id+1;
```

But much better use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php) which will give you inserted record **id** to avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: i've tried both, but it still didn't work, btw i've set my id into "no auto increment", it is right? i've no idea how to do it, can u show me some example based on my code? thanks before

Comment: mysql_insert_id will obviously not work if the field is not auto increment. However, in this case I think the field should be an auto incrementing field!

Comment: $newId = mysql_insert_id($hasil); i've tried it with autoincrement, but the second one came with no name. just ".jpg" that's it, am i missing something?

Comment: try code like this:
`CREATE TABLE animals (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));`

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES ('dog');") or die(mysql_error());
var_dump(mysql_insert_id());`